# Modify WooTabs Popular Posts to work with pageviews rather than comment counts

Tags: wordpress, woothemes

The woo tabs widget display the popular posts based on comment counts rather than page views. The code from the widget than enables this is

$popular = get_posts( array( 'suppress_filters' => false, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'comment_count', 'numberposts' => $posts ) );
    foreach($popular as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
?>

Can anyone help me modify thsi so that it works with page views rather than comment counts???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and after a bit of research came up with the following:

I added this snippet to my functions.php file:

[**Track post views without a plugin using post meta**](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/)

Then from **step 2** of that link I pasted this code snippet above the widget code:

```
<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

And finally changed 'orderby' => 'comment_count' to 'orderby' => 'post_views' as below:

```
$popular = get_posts( array( 'suppress_filters' => false, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'post_views', 'numberposts' => $posts ) );
    foreach($popular as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
```

Hope this helps :)